# does PHP APC as local object store have any limits besides storage size?

Tags: php, apc

I'm using PHP APC on production servers of a web service with 10M's hits/day successfuly for a long time.

I'm considering offloading much more data to the APC local cache.

Theoretically it looks to me that since APC call is mainly a local memory access. It should not become an issue to call it 10,000s of times/sec. As far as I can tell its limits can be in the memory size but as long as the server has free CPU it should not have performance or corruption issues at high rates.

Is there any limit I'm not aware of that might prevent me from using APC's local object cache in very high rate on app server (ubuntu).

Update:
Apparently according to the answers below my question wasn't clear. I'm not looking for alternaive caching options (memcache,redis etc..). My question is whether there is any concern or limit in using local APC in very high rates and read concurrency.

Comment: One server's APC cache can't be accessed from other server's if you're in a mult-server environment... APC can't be shared with/between CLI tasks

Comment: yes. I know. for this I will use memcached as 2nd level cache so when a new app server lanunches it will read the data from memcache and not the db. but during regular operations I need the data as close as possible so it will be duplicated on app servers.

Comment: Love this question and APC is a totally underutilized caching layer. Would love to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm personally a big fan of using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for this kind of storage. It has several advantages:

- It's a program that focuses entirely on the storage, and development of memcached will always focus on that. APC is primarily a cache for code, which just happens to offer some access to user storage.
- When you reload or restart Apache (or whatever webserver you use), APC's cache gets emptied. When you use a standalone solution such as memcached, you can control when the cache gets emptied. This is really something that was very important in my case, as I sometimes have to make changes to Apache's configuration and really don't want to clear the cache when I do, as it creates a large CPU spike (loading data into the cache again).
- It has the possibility to create a distributed cache, making it more scalable. When you have to add a second server because your website becomes large, you don't want two caches which cache the same stuff. memcached scales well, while APC's cache doesn't.

There are many other advantages of using memcached over APC's user cache, but for me these were the primary three reasons to not use APC's user cache. I do use APC, of course, just not the user cache.

Comment: And a note RE: @MarkBaker's comment on the question: memcached **can** be shared between CLI tasks, and is very useful in multi-server environments.

Comment: redis is even better because multiple redis servers can replicate stored data... so if you lose one server from the cluster the data is still available in the others.... plus it's gee-whizz fast

Comment: Hi Tom,
I use memcached for part of the data. For the specific data I want to add I need something much faster than memcache. I plan to use memcache as 2nd stage buffer for this specific data so if its not in APC memcached will be searched and if its not there the db will be hit. The main reason is that when additional app servers get launched, I dont want the db to be hit for this specific data.

Comment: @MarkBaker: isn't redis more of a database than a cache?

Comment: @Tom - falls kinda halfway between the two.... it's great used as a cache... personally I'm still not overly impressed with NoSQL databases (including redis) for that type of data storage, but I'm more than happy using redis as an alternative to memcache because of that clustered redis failover capability

Comment: @Nir: A big problem with that approach is that you'll be using a LOT of extra memory, which you probably don't want. Also note that adding a memcached server generally doesn't require that many DB calls, as most of the data can simply stay where it is at that moment.

Comment: @Nir: And: your approach (double cache) will probably only cause all of memcached's data to be in APC as well. The only difference in speed which you'll really notice is that the network latency will be gone.

Comment: Tom, Mark,
Please see my edit in the question. I'm not interested in other caching options. In fact any solution which requires a network roundtrip will be too slow for the kind of data I want to cache. 
And Tom the double cache in memcache is for speed of new app server warmup. so a new app server wont hammer the db. It will also allow debugging on app servers without warmup issues.